# ASP.NetCore - RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using [ASP.Net Core 1.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core). My model is like this-

```
public class JobCircular
{
    [Key]
    public UInt64 Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

    public JobCircular()
    {
        AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

My database for the DBModel is like this-

[image]

And I am doing this in controller-

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    UInt16 year = (UInt16)rnd.Next(1999, 2017);

    var jobCircular1 = context.JobCirculars;

    JobCircular jobCircular = context.JobCirculars
                                .SingleOrDefault(j => j.Id == 1);

    ...........................
    ...........................
}
```

And I am getting this error-

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalSqlGenerationHelper.GenerateLiteralValue(float)' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalSqlGenerationHelper.GenerateLiteralValue(decimal)'
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , RelationalSqlGenerationHelper , object )
```

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Take a look at this similar issue: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8259. Seems that it's an EF Core library issue.

Comment: In that case, what can I do? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because `Unsigned Int 64` is not *currently* supported in Entity Framework (as at v6). Use a `Long` instead of a `UInt64` that maps to a SQL `bigint`.

See the [Conversion Table](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx):

```
+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| C# DataType        | Related DB Column DataType | PK Column DataType & Length         |
+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------+ 
| int                | int                        | int, Identity column increment by 1 |
| string             | nvarchar(Max)              | nvarchar(128)                       |
| decimal            | decimal(18,2)              | decimal(18,2)                       |
| float              | real                       | real                                |
| byte[]             | varbinary(Max)             | varbinary(128)                      |
| datetime           | datetime                   | datetime                            |
| bool               | bit                        | bit                                 |
| byte               | tinyint                    | tinyint                             |
| short              | smallint                   | smallint                            |
| long               | bigint                     | bigint                              |
| double             | float                      | float                               |
| char               | No mapping                 | No mapping                          |
| sbyte              | No mapping                 |                                     |
| (throws exception) | No mapping                 |                                     |
| object             | No mapping                 | No mapping                          |
+--------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have tried `udouble` and it does not work also. Then I have tried `double` and it worked.